# How to save fragment instance?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have a `BottomNavigationView` from the support library with four items each item has a fragment associated with it . I wonder how to correctly handle fragments transactions as I want to avoid creating the fragment each time.. when I use replace the fragment recreated every time .. and when using add the second time I click the item I got `IllegalStateException` (fragment already added). So what is the correct way for hanging such situation ?

**update**
This is the code that describes this .. How I can avoid recreation of `FragmentB` every time?

https://github.com/kadymuhammad/DarkSide

Comment: try to use viewpager

Comment: Have you tried setRetainedInstance(true) ?

Comment: It will make the saved bundle null every time

Comment: Give some code to understand more the situation